# Add data/rows to UITableView within ViewController. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

How do I populate a UITableView Within a UIViewController?
The UITableView is dynamic and uses prototype cells.

(Using Swift)

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fGkF.png)

Comment: Add more info. What do you need 2 prototype cells for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do following :

```
import UIKit

class tableViewOne: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    // your data
    var dummyData = ["data 0","data 1","data 2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}

extension tableViewOne: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    // Define no of rows in your tableView
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dummyData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Default cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = dummyData[indexPath.row]

        return cell;
    }

}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to setup `DataSource` and `Delegate` of `UITableView` in the `storyboard`. No need to define programmatically if already defined in `storyboard`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! Clean answer!

Answer (score 2):

1. You will need to ctrl + drag your `table view` into your View Controller.
2. In the `viewDidLoad()` inside your View Controller, you will need to set the delegate and the datasource:

   ```
   tableView.dataSource = self
   tableView.delegate = self
   ```
3. Your View Controller will need to implement:

   ```
   class YourViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
   ```

Now, your ViewController class will need to implement relevant methods that return cell/number of rows etc.

Good luck.